# Microsoft 365: Users are not able to use alternate authentification methods

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, active-directory, office365, microsoft365

I use Microsoft 365 for my 5-person business and am currently very satisfied, even if it is not always easy.

Under "Security -> Authentication methods -> Policies" I have enabled the following methods for all users (target).

- Microsoft Authenticator
- SMS / Text message
- Email OTP

However, when my users log in to Microsoft 365 for the first time and are asked to protect their account, they can only select Microsoft Authenticator. The option for alternative methods is not shown at all (only myself can do it ...). Users can only select the "other authenticator app" option.

What am I doing wrong? We have 1 colleague who has such an old phone that she can't even download Microsoft Authenticator from the Play Store. She should have the option that she can use SMS + Mail.

I am very grateful for your help!

Kind regards,
Dennis

- Administrate with Azure Active Directory (Security -> Authentication methods -> Policies)

Answer (score 1):

You may have security defaults enabled.

[Security Defaults in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults)

You may also want to check that you do not have conditional access policies in place to only allow signing in from web portals or Office 365 apps via app-based MFA.